# discord.py changing embed page will change pages in all embeds

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

If I type the command twice and try to change page in one embed, It will change pages in both embeds.
This also happens If I type different commands, It will always change pages on all embeds..
How do I fix this?

```py
            msg = await ctx.send(embed=pages[current].set_footer(text=f"{current+1}/{len(pages)}"))
            
            for button in buttons:
                await msg.add_reaction(button)
                
            while True:
                try:
                    reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji in buttons, timeout=30.0)

                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    pass

                else:
                    previous_page = current
                    if reaction.emoji == u"\u23EA":
                        current = 0
                        
                    elif reaction.emoji == u"\u2B05":
                        if current > 0:
                            current -= 1
                            
                    elif reaction.emoji == u"\u27A1":
                        if current < len(pages)-1:
                            current += 1

                    elif reaction.emoji == u"\u23E9":
                        current = len(pages)-1

                    for button in buttons:
                        await msg.remove_reaction(button, ctx.author)

                    if current != previous_page:
                        await msg.edit(embed=pages[current].set_footer(text=f"{current+1}/{len(pages)}"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, your check function returns if the author is the command author and the emoji is the correct emoji, we also need to check for message id if we want the check to return true only for that message.
Your check should be,

```py
check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji in buttons and reaction.message.id == msg.id
```

where `msg` is the message you sent and added reactions to.

### References:

- [`Reaction.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.Reaction.message)